# Core Data: Where is SingleViewCoreData.sqlite being saved?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am quite new to core data, which is why I am at the beginning of a learning process.

Today I tried to save Data from a SpriteKit Game in CoreData, which resulted in a bunch of errors.

Because the game template from XCode does not provide the use of core data, I had to import the Appdelegate Code (CoreData Stack) from a singleview Template. And this is where the problems begin - I guess.

I inspected the persistent store coordinator and I found:

```
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
```

First, I can not find the "SingleViewCoreData.sqlite" file in the project directory. So where is it stored? Or is it created automatically?

Second I got the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Error. I think there might be a link to the first question?

Thanks so far. I hope you can understand my bad english.

Krusel

Comment: The .sqlite is created automatically and managed by Xcode - you won't be able to see it or find it easily, nor should you.

Comment: The file is created at runtime and stored at the URL you create in your code example (the `url` constant).  You can execute `print("\(url.absolutePath)")` if you'd like to see where it is created.  Having said that @RyanCollins is correct, you shouldn't modify those files outside of using `CoreData`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will it be created, even if you add the core data stack manually?